# Coldfusion: Formatting of createDate() output

Tags: coldfusion

After finishing an order the server is sending an email with the order data.
In that mail there is a createDate function but in the Mail the date looks like this:

[e-mail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fGOTs.png)

instead of like

```
01.08.2017
```

The whole template is included in a cfmail.

```
<cfmail spoolenable="false" from="#application.kontaktmail#"
 to="#getUser.strEmail#"
 bcc="#application.mailOrder#"
 server="#application.mailserver#"
 useSSL="#application.mailServerUseSSL#"
 useTLS="#application.mailServerUseTLS#"
 subject="#subjectText#" type="html">
 <cfinclude template="cfm/getMailBody.cfm" />
</cfmail>
```

In the getMailBody.cfm there is a template that contains a table element.
In that there are several cfinclude to get the data.

The datetime output at the end looks like following:

```
<cfset cellValue = CreateDateTime(#cellValue_year#,#cellValue_month#,#cellValue_day#,#cellValue_hour#,#cellValue_minute#,0) />
```

Everywhere it is correct but when I am doing an output of that date, just in the Mail it looks wrong with the brackets.

I don't know why. Can you help me to solve this issue?

Comment: I would recommend posting your code.

Comment: ColdFusion has a dateformat function.

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
<cfset cellValue = CreateDateTime(#cellValue_year#
,#cellValue_month#
,#cellValue_day#
,#cellValue_hour#
,#cellValue_minute#,0) />
```

to this

```
<cfset dateTime = CreateDateTime(cellValue_year
, cellValue_month
, cellValue_day
, cellValue_hour
, cellValue_minute, 0) />

<cfset cellValue = dateFormat(dateTime, 'mask of your choice') 
& ' ' & timeformat(dateTime, 'mask of your choice')>
```

If you are on a recent enough version of ColdFusion, there is a dateTimeFormat function available.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I really appreciate it. Unfortunately I got the same result with the date in brackets. The datetime for itself it is not the problem, it is the formatting in the e-mail.

Comment: If that's the case, you should edit your question and show the code that displays this variable.

Comment: The cfset you see above is exactly the code that I get to outpout in the mail.

Comment: Also keep in mind that date formatting masks may be different in `dateFormat()` and `dateTimeFormat()` and any other masks (like `PL-SQL`) that you may use. '`MM/DD/YYYY`' isn't always the same as '`MM/DD/YYYY`'. Nor is it always the same as '`mm/dd/yyyy`'.